# how to store index in disk blocks consistently

Tags: c, database, database-design

I am building a database engine in C for Linux and I need to implement indexing.
Consider a simple double linked list index like this:

```
struct node_t {
   void *prev;
   void *next;
   long  data;
};
```

For permanent storage I have to convert this structure in disk blocks, like for example:

```
struct node_on_disk_t {
    size_t prev_disk_block;
    short  prev_disk_offset;
    size_t next_disk_block;
    short  next_disk_offset;
    long   data;
};
```

Now, when I insert a record, one entry must be added to the index too. If the index is only few elements I can store it on 1 disk block consistently because the write() of 1 block is atomic. However if the list fills entirely the first block, another block must be added on insert and pointers must be updated on both blocks. But the problem is, only 1 block can be written atomically. So, my question is how to store this kind of structure consistently?

Can this be done without transaction log? Because I could store the description of the operation on another disk block first (sort of transaction log), update the pointers of the index and then remove the description of the operation, but this would have to be done in 3 write()s , too slow

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `[database-design]`. Please remove this tag.

Comment: As an aside: Are you sure this is how you want to implement an index? A database index is usually meant to improve access times. A doubly linked list isn't the best way to achieve that.

Comment: @ArjunShankar yes I am sure. when the user will click on 'Next' or 'Previous' buttons within the application, he will only want to watch next or previous data, so there is no need to read complete index, because it may have millions of records

Comment: That is not what a [database index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) is for really, but okay.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Ok, so how to store a double linked list when the list is longer than 1 sector then?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Protect your data structure from concurrent writers or protect it from non-graceful shutdown (e.g. due to a power-cut), or both?

Comment: protect it from non-graceful shutdowns, to ensure consistency of ACID

Answer (score 0):

There are two common strategies:

1. Transaction logging
2. Copy-on-write

The latter one works by always copying new and changed data to new sectors and after the new image has been set up, link it in using one atomic sector write.

Unfortunately, I don't see how this could work for a doubly linked-list. For a singly-linked list it works.